# Preloading web fonts with visibility: hidden; bad for SEO?

Tags: css, seo

I've started using a method to preload the webfonts via hiding them; whilst it works great, I'm not sure if "hiding text" will be viewed as bad for SEO?

All I do is something like this:

CSS;

```
.preload {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    font-family: Roboto, Arial;
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="preload">
    Preload Light Font
</div>
```

Thoughts!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google cares about this when you are using keywords or links in the text that you are hiding.  In your case you are doing neither.  You have only three words, none of which you would be trying to rank for.  You have no links.

Just using `visibility: hidden` is not a red flag to Google.  There are many legitimate uses of it such as tooltips where it is hidden until the user reveals it.

If you wanted to be even safer, you could put only common words like "the" and "and" inside the preload blocks.